# Excel VBA: Find - compare two files - copy

Tags: excel, vba, search, copy, paste

I am new with VBA, trying since 12h serveral codes and didnt get it fixed. I really hope you can help me!

I have two Excel-Files
For Example it looks like this:
[Input File1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EUqi.png)

It should find the month via dropdown (January, February,....) and copy the specific cells below to Excel-File 2 under January, February,....

Additionally it should search the word which is choosen by dropdown (KW1, KW2, KW3,....) and copy the cell-values under A B C D E in the Excel-File 2.

Like:
[Master File2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zLkS.png)

The Excel-File 2 is the "Master-Excel" and with the button "werte_uebergeben" you can send the values from File1 (A1:A11) to File2 into (A1:A11) or (B1:B11)... depends on the headline

With the button "Country" in File1 you can send the line for JP with the cells (E25:I25) to File2 in (G28:K28) - depends on the word KW1, KW2 (G35:K35) or KW3 (G42:K42).

I really hope it would be a little bit clearer to understand with the pictures.

Here is a snippet for the 2nd Job but it should paste it automatically in the line with "KW1". Also it should put in the KW1, KW2... I chose

```
Sub country_Click()
Dim wsIRow As Long, wsORow As Long
Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range
Dim Kalenderwoche As String

Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")
Set wsO = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\MM\\Mappe2.xlsx").Worksheets("Tabelle1")
Kalenderwoche = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(1, 1).Value

wsORow = wsO.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

With wsI
    wsIRow = wsI.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

    Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & wsIRow)

    With rng
        Set aCell = .Find(What:="LOC", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

            wsO.Cells.Find(What:="LOC", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
         SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(1, 1).Value = aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                         wsO.Cells.Find(What:="LOC", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
         SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(1, 2).Value = aCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                         wsO.Cells.Find(What:="LOC", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
         SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(1, 3).Value = aCell.Offset(0, 3).Value

        End If
    End With
End With





Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Thank you very very very much in advance!!
Best regards
Markus

edit: guess its working now :D :D

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which part you were having trouble with but I guess it is first searching for the KW section and then continuing the search to find the country below it. If that's  the case perhaps this helps.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Country_Click()

     ' country
    Dim wsIn As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rngOut As Range
    Dim KW As String, Country As String

    Set wsIn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    Set wsOut = Workbooks.Open("C:\...\Mappe2.xlsx").Worksheets("Tabelle1")

    KW = wsIn.Range("D24").Value
    Set rng = wsIn.Range("D25:I25")
    Country = rng.Cells(1, 1)

    Set rngOut = wsOut.UsedRange.Find(KW)
    If rngOut Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox KW & "Not FOund", vbExclamation
    Else
        MsgBox KW & " Found at " & rngOut.Address, vbInformation
        Set rngOut = wsOut.UsedRange.Find(Country, rngOut)
        If rngOut Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox Country & " Not Found", vbExclamation
        Else
            MsgBox Country & " Found at " & rngOut.Address, vbInformation
            rng.Copy rngOut
            MsgBox rng.Address & " copied to " & rngOut.Address, vbInformation
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

The month button is simpler and since you have validation on cell A1 with a dropdown  you could remove the case block.

```
Private Sub Mth_Click()

    ' month
    Dim wsIn As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rngOut As Range, mthno As Integer

    Set wsIn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    Set wsOut = Workbooks.Open("C:\...\Mappe2.xlsx").Worksheets("Tabelle1")

    Set rng = wsIn.Range("A1:A7")

    Select Case LCase(Left(rng.Cells(1, 1), 3))
        Case "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", _
             "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "now", "dec"

            mthno = Month("1 " & rng.Cells(1, 1))
            rng.Copy wsOut.Range("A1").Offset(0, mthno - 1)
            MsgBox "Copied to month " & mthno, vbInformation

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error with Month " & rng.Cells(1, 1), vbCritical
    End Select

End Sub
```